# upload image canvas jquery

Tags: jquery, html

For some dependencies I have to upload to the server images 670 X 525 px (whatever is the original size of the image that users upload). So the idea was draw image into canvas

`canvasContext.drawImage(0, 0, myimageSelector.naturalWidth, myimageSelector.naturalHeight, 0, 0, 670, 525);`

convert the canvas to blob then upload the blob to the server it and it worked.

```
var dataUrl= mycanvasSelector.toDataUrl('image/png');
var blob = convertDataUrlToBlob(dataUrl);
// upload blob as image 
...
```

But when I looked at the uploaded images on the server I noticed that images size increased at least by 5 times compared to the original image size. is there any idea to reduce size before uploading. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), then you can process the images with the [canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images).

[This Mozilla Hacks blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/) post walks you through most of the process. For reference here's the assembled source code from the blog post:

```
// from an input element
var filesToUpload = input.files;
var file = filesToUpload[0];

var img = document.createElement("img");
var reader = new FileReader();  
reader.onload = function(e) {img.src = e.target.result}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;

if (width > height) {
  if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
    width = MAX_WIDTH;
  }
} else {
  if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
  }
}
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

//Post dataurl to the server with AJAX
```